# The navigation bar for my programmatic side menu won't appear after navigating from a different view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

After following a tutorial for making a side menu programmatically without pods I have come upon an issue regarding my navigation.  I have my login view set as the root view controller, in which after logging in I will be presented with the home view. When this transition happnes the navigation bar that should be appearing for the side menu is does not appear and thus I can't access my side menu.  I know my side menu works because when I set the home view as the root controlle rthe bar shows up allowing me to click the side menu.

Scene delegate:

```
var window: UIWindow?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
    let nav = UINavigationController()
    let mainView = LogInController()
    nav.viewControllers = [mainView]
    window?.rootViewController = nav
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

The transitions I use in the log in controller:

```
    let homeView = HomeMenu()
    homeView.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
    homeView.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(homeView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

- I do not want to use pods
- I am using firebase
- I also have a signup
- When I leave the home menu and then come back I still want the bar to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I instead just added a navigation bar programmatically and from there added accessed my side menu.